# How do I manually use the @2x or @3x image from my Assets.xcassets file in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, assets

I am projecting my app's screen onto another screen and noticed the images in my app's buttons look slightly blurry on the external screen. I would like to use the same image except manually use its @2x or @3x image size when I know my screen is projecting.

I have searched around and not found a great answer, can this be done programmatically in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Make a UITraitCollection whose `displayScale` is 2 or 3, as desired.

- UITraitCollection [`init(displayScale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1623518-init)

Now use that trait collection, or a combination of the current trait collection with that trait collection, to fetch that variety of your image from the asset collection.

- UIImage [`init(named:in:compatibleWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624154-init)